# No error for not initializing reference variable of class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am a newbie and have a basic doubt about relationship between object creation and constructors.

**Program- 1**

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class xxx{
     private: int x;
     public: xxx(){cout<<"constructer is called"<<endl;}
 };
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     xxx x1;        //Constructor is called
     return 0;
 }
```

**Output- constructor is called**

**Program- 2**

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class xxx{
     private: int x;
     public: xxx(){cout<<"constructer is called"<<endl;}
 };
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     xxx x1();        //Constructor xxx() is not called.
     return 0;
 }
```

**Output- blank**
Any information is very helpfule

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned, this is referred to as the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - this is not the most vexing parse. It's simply a function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 xxx x1;
```

creates an object of class `xxx`, therefore, calls default constructor of class `xxx`.

```
xxx x1();
```

declares a function that returns an object of class `xxx` and function name is `x1`, takes no parameter. It is not an instantiation of class `xxx`, therefore, there is no constructor being called.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
xxx x1();
```

is a function declaration (function called `x1` taking no arguments and returning an `xxx`), not a variable declaration so no instance of `xxx` is created (hence no constructor call).